# Itertools instead of nested loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-itertools

```
list_a = [] 
for color in [True,False]:
    for piece in range(1,7):
        list_a = list_a + function(piece,color)
```

Here the `function(piece,color)` returns a list, which I want to join and finally return the long list, can `itertools.chain` be used here? because I think it might be faster. I am only displaying an example, but in my actual code the loop runs about 100,000 times, which is why I am looking for a faster method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to answer the question you should have asked instead ;-)

This:

```
list_a = list_a + function(piece,color)
```

takes time quadratic in the number of times it's executed.  Each time, a brand new list object is created, copying the entirety of the old `list_a` and the new list.

So if it's executed many times, you can get a huge improvement by changing it to this:

```
list_a.extend(function(piece,color))
```

Then `list_a` is extended "in place" whenever possible; under the covers, it *may* need to make a copy to a larger memory area from time to time, but overall the amortized time is linear in the number of times it's executed.

Comment: The best sorts of answers explain both how to fix it as well as *why* they were wrong. None of the others explain why `lst = lst + ele` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* want to use `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import product, chain
>>> list_a = list(chain.from_iterable(function(piece, color) for piece, color in product([True, False], range(1, 7))))
```

Of course, if you use `list_a += function(piece, color)` this would likely be just as fast (maybe faster?).

The problem with `list_a = list_a + function(piece, color)` is that this line is *quadratic* in it's input, because it builds an entirely new list, whereas `list_a += function(piece, color)` is the equivalent of using `extend`, which for Python lists is amortized constant time, so the inner part stays linear instead of quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

`yield from` seems to be the simple solution here.

```
def generator():
    for color in [True,False]:
        for piece in range(1,7):
            yield from function(piece,color)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.starmap`, although you'll still have the loops, you can't really escape from them:

```
result_generator = starmap(function, ((piece, color) for piece in range(1,7) for color in [True,False]))

list_a = list(result_generator)
```

Then, use `itertools.product` like this:

```
result_generator = starmap(function, product(range(1,7), [True,False]))
```